# How can I keep the check state of multiple Virtual Tree View nodes in sync?

Tags: delphi, checkbox, duplicates, virtualtreeview

My tree has 2 levels of nodes - it's a **Contact List** style tree.

My problem is, that I would like to have every contact checked, in all the "Contact Categories". Here is a screenshot of my contact list as it looks now (And yes, I have permission to post it)

[image: Contact List]

As you see, **Todd Hirsch** is checked in the Category **Test Category**, but not in **All Contacts**. What I am trying to achieve, is to have a contact have the same **checked status** in every category.

Example: I check Todd Hirsch in the Test Category - Todd Hirsch is automatically checked in All Contacts (And every other category). If I check Todd Hirsch in the All Contacts, he will also get checked in Test Category. If I Uncheck Todd Hirsch in All Contacts, he will also get unchecked in Test Category.

I tried doing it through the VirtualStringtree's OnChecking events, by looping thru the whole tree for each node in the tree, however when the contact list is big (2000 +), it is very slow, and when there's like 5000+, it might even crash my program **(Application has stopped working)**

What do you suggest?

Here is the code that I use to make sure that a contact is only checked once. (That is not what I *want* now, but it's what I am using right now.)

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// HasDuplicateChecked
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Function HasDuplicateChecked(Node: PVirtualNode): PVirtualNode;
Var
  ParentNode, ChildNode: PVirtualNode;
  I, J: Integer;
Begin

  // IHCW
  Result := Nil;

  // Get the first node of the tree..
  ParentNode := VT.GetFirst;

  // Loop thru the parent nodes.
  for I := 0 to VT.RootNodeCount - 1 do
  begin
    // Get the first child node.
    ChildNode := ParentNode.FirstChild;
    // Loop thru the children..
    for J := 0 to ParentNode.ChildCount - 1 do
    begin
      // If the ChildNode is checked...
      if NodeIsChecked(ChildNode) then
        // And it is NOT the passed node..
        if ChildNode <> Node then
          // but the data matches..
          if GetData(ChildNode).SkypeID = GetData(Node).SkypeID then
          begin
            // Then pass the Childnode as a result, and EXIT!
            Result := ChildNode;
            Exit;
          end;
      // Next child..
      ChildNode := ChildNode.NextSibling;
    end;
    // Next parent...
    ParentNode := ParentNode.NextSibling;
  end;

End;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// vtSkypeChecking
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
procedure TSkypeListEventHandler.vtSkypeChecking(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; var NewState: TCheckState; var Allowed: Boolean);
Var
  Level: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  Child: PVirtualNode;
begin
  // Allow the checking..
  Allowed := True;
  // Get the Level..
  Level := Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node);

  // If the level is 0 (Category Level)
  if Level = 0 then
  begin
    // And if the Node's Childcount is more than 0
    if Node.ChildCount > 0 then
    Begin
      // Get the first child..
      Child := Node.FirstChild;
      // Loop thru the children..
      for I := 0 to Node.ChildCount - 1 do
      begin
        // Set the checkstate, and go next..
        Child.CheckState := NewState;
        Child := Child.NextSibling;
      end;
    End;
  end;


  // If the level is 1 (User Level)
  if Level = 1 then
  begin
    // and if the Node's parent is not Nil..
    if Node.Parent <> nil then
    begin
      // aaand, if the new state is Unchecked...
      if (NewState = csUncheckedNormal) or (NewState = csUncheckedPressed) then
      begin
        // .. and if the node checkstate is checked..
        if NodeIsChecked(Node) then
        Begin
          // Set the PARENT node's checkstate to Unchecked!
          Node.Parent.CheckState := csUncheckedNormal;
        End;

      end;
      // BUT, if there is a DUPLICATE of the node, screw the above, and
      // forbid the checking!
      if HasDuplicateChecked(Node) <> nil then
        Allowed := False;

    end;
  end;

  // Uncheck all the duplicates.
  UncheckDuplicates;

  // Refresh the Tree
  Sender.Refresh;

end;
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are suffering from a recursion problem? When you change the checked property in an OnCheckedChanged event handler then don't you end up going around the list again? You could try a quick hack and block re-entrant calls to your OnCheckedChanged event handler or whatever it is called.

Comment: @David I am using the OnChecking event. What I do now, is that I **block** "second checks" (so each contact can only be checked once), and I do that by going thru the list, and for each node, I go thru the list **AGAIN** to locate the duplicates, and make sure no duplicate is checked. That is obviously the wrong way of doing it, but it's the only way I got so far.

Comment: @Jeff I've no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @David - Let me post the code

Comment: Jeff - you should look into recursion.

Comment: @Simon - Isn't that what I am doing? If not, please enlighten me :)

Comment: Recursion is the notion of calling the same method within the method. At no point in you code, does the HasDuplicateChecked() call itself. What you are doing is called iteration, not recursion. You are looping through all parent nodes, then the child nodes. This can be acheived (IMO more cleanly) using recursion.

Comment: @Simon - I am not sure how that would help - why not post an answer about how you would do it? :)

Comment: Your right, its not really going to help your problem, but more to make you aware about the principal of recursion. Using iteration still acheives your task

Comment: @Simon - Would there be a difference in speed?

Comment: minimal, if any. Still you shouldnt be having speed issues when using VST. It sounds like the is another underlying issue.

Comment: @Simon - Well the way my code is in the OP, is how it is now, and it's slow when handling like 4000 children. Am I doing anything wrong? Is it because I store the data in the node? Honestly I dont see how storing it in a seperate data structure would make it any faster - whats the explanation to that? :)

Comment: Please read Rob K's Answer. What is probably happening is when you check a node, it then tries to check the other node of the same contact, which then tries to check any other nodes of the same contact and so on. The OnCheck() event fires not only from UI but also in code. Also using Tristatechecking will solve half of your issues, and then all you should be doing is scanning the tree ONCE to check any other contacts of the same name.

Comment: @Simon - when I used the TristateChecking, it made it even slower. Also, the reason I use the OnChecking event, is because (AFAIK) it only runs when node is being checked from UI. If I use the OnChecked, wouldn't that cause it to run too many times?

Comment: @Simon - And also, Rob's method did not solve the speed issue either. :S

Comment: If its running slow, then there is something else in your code that is causing it to. VST is fast. Its hard to try and debug without seeing your whole project. But you really need to run it through a profiler to try and see where all the cycles are being used. Have a look at all of your event handlers for the tree. something, somewhere is causing it to slow down. Trust me, VST can handle <10,000 nodes with ease.

Comment: Try this: Remove all of your event handlers from the tree. Run the project and see how it responds. Then try adding an event handler one by one, to see where it slows down. Start with OnGetText, then OnChecked etc.

Comment: @Simon - I was using the OnChecked event to update my statusbar, which loops thru the whole tree to get the checked children, so THATS what was causing it! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `OnChecking` is the wrong event to handle. You want `OnChecked`. `OnChecking` really justs ask, "Is this node's check state allowed to change?" It's *not* meant to go off and check other nodes. Use `OnChecked` for that.

Second, you shouldn't need to handle the check-state of the category nodes. Turn on the `toAutoTristateTracking` option and the control will automatically adjust the states of all related child and parent nodes. (Change a parent, and all the children change. Change a child, and the parent changes to "indeterminate.")

Your code seems to be on the right track otherwise, though. When a child node changes, you need to find all the *other* copies of that node in the rest of the tree and change their check states to match the new state of the just-changed node. The time it takes to perform that operation should be linearly in the number of nodes in the tree — double the number of nodes, and it should take roughly twice the amount of time to find all the duplicates. But even with a few thousand nodes, it should finish in the blink of an eye. If it takes longer, there's some other time-consuming operation that you haven't shown here. Try using a profiler to discover the bottleneck.

The code below traverses once through all the nodes in the tree. It temporarily disables the `OnChecked` event handler because otherwise, each time it changes the state of one of the duplicates, the event would run again. If the new check state is the same as the current one, the event doesn't run, so there's no danger of infinite recursion, but disabling the event does prevent it from doing lots of redundant traversals through the tree.

```
procedure PropagateCheckState(Tree: TVirtualStringTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PNodeData;
  TargetID: string;
  Parent: PVirtualNode;
  FoundOne: Boolean;
begin
  Data := Tree.GetNodeData(Node);
  TargetID := Data.SkypeID;

  Parent := Tree.GetFirst;
  while Assigned(Parent) do begin
    // Assume no user appears twice in the same category
    if Parent <> Tree.NodeParent[Node] then begin
      FoundOne := False;
      Child := Tree.GetFirstChild(Parent);
      while Assigned(Child) and not FoundOne do begin
        Data := Tree.GetNodeData(Child);
        if Data.SkypeID = TargetID then begin
          // Found a duplicate. Sync it with Node.
          Tree.CheckState[Child] := Tree.CheckState[Node];
          FoundOne := True;
        end;
        Child := Tree.GetNextSibling(Child);
      end;
    end;
    Parent := Tree.GetNextSibling(Parent);
  end;
end;

procedure TSkypeListEventHandler.vtSkypeChecked(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  CheckedEvent: TVTChangeEvent;
begin
  if Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) = 0 then
    exit; // The tree cascades changes automatically

  Assert(Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) = 1, 'Unexpected node level');
  // We'll be accessing members that are protected in TBaseVirtualTree, but
  // they're public in TVirtualStringTree, so make sure we're still operating
  // on the same tree.
  Assert(Sender = vtSkype);

  CheckedEvent := vtSkype.OnChecked;
  vtSkype.OnChecked := nil;
  try
    PropagateCheckState(vtSkype, Node);
  finally
    vtSkype.OnChecked := CheckedEvent;
  end;
end;
```

If your data structure had a list of all the nodes associated with a given user ID, it would be much more straightforward:

```
procedure PropagateCheckState(Tree: TVirtualStringTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PNodeData;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Data := Tree.GetNodeData(Node);

  for i := 0 to Pred(Data.User.Nodes.Count) do
    Tree.CheckState[Data.User.Nodes[i]] := Tree.CheckState[Node];
end;
```

Even if you continue to store all your data in the tree control itself (which you've been advised many times is a bad idea), you can still use a secondary data structure to act as an *index* for tree nodes, keyed off the user ID. If you have a sufficiently recent Delphi version, you can use `TDictionary<string, TList<PVirtualNode>>`. Then `PropagateCheckState` could look like this:

```
uses Generics.Collections;

var
  UserNodes: TDictionary<string, TList<PVirtualNode>>;

procedure PropagateCheckState(Tree: TVirtualStringTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PNodeData;
  Nodes: TList<PVirtualNode>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Data := Tree.GetNodeData(Node);

  if not UserNodes.TryGetValue(Data.SkypeID, Nodes) then
    exit; // Weird. The node's ID isn't in the index at all.

  for i := 0 to Pred(Nodes.Count) do
    Tree.CheckState[Nodes[i]] := Tree.CheckState[Node];
end;
```

Make sure to update the `UserNodes` index whenever you add or remove a user in a category.

Comment: +1 - Thanks, however I am getting this Compiler error: "Cannot access private symbol TBaseVirtualTree.GetNodeParent" at "if Parent <> Tree.GetNodeParent(Node)".

Comment: Oh, sorry. Use the `NodeParent` property instead.

Comment: It works, but when I click the Checkbox in the Category node, it freezes for like 3 seconds - why is that? It did not do that with my method?

Comment: In fact, when I do it with the All Contacts node, which contains like 400 children, it takes 6 seconds or more.

Comment: When you check the category node, the tree automatically checks all the children. That causes the `OnChecked` event to be fired once for each child, which causes searches through the tree's other nodes.

Comment: Well, that's a problem. :/ What do you suggest?

Comment: Use a data structure more suited to the task. Even if it's not the *primary* data structure, you clearly have a need for finding all related nodes, so set up an index that lets you look up the list of nodes. If it's keyed off the user ID, you'd use something like `TDictionary<string, TList<PVirtualNode>>`. Update the index each time a user is added to or removed from a category.

Comment: So basically have a, say, TStringlist, of all the users?

Comment: Honestly I have no clue of how to implement this.. (Don't worry, I know I suck)

Comment: @Rob - I don't hope it's too much to ask, but would you mind editing your answer to reflect your suggestion, or should I post a new question for that? Thank you :)

Comment: I realized that sticking with my old method would be easier for my other routines to handle - but this was the correct answer, even though it was not as fast as I had hope. :P

Comment: @Rob - So will the UserNodes contain ALL my users, or will I make a UserNodes for each category?

Comment: Yes, it would contain all the users. I suppose if a user were in just one category, it wouldn't need to be in the index (because there'd be no other nodes to update in the tree), but it should be easier to just manage everything the same way instead of keeping track of that as a special case.

Comment: @Rob **"Make sure to update the UserNodes index whenever you add or remove a user in a category."** well if all the users are in the UserList, why would I need to update the index? I still dont seem to be getting it. :)

Comment: Jeff, the index tells you which PVirtualNodes correspond to the same single user. When a user is added to a category, you haven't changed the number of users, but you *have* changed the number of nodes in the tree control. The index maps users to *lists* of nodes. You've added a node to the tree, so you need to add that same node to one of the node lists in the index.

Comment: @Rob so basically have a TList, of TLists with PVirtualNodes..?.. I still don't follow :S

Comment: Don't use a TList of TLists. You need something that can *map* a string to a list, so you need something capable of holding strings *and* lists. TList is not suitable for holding strings. I guess you don't have a version of Delphi that comes with TDictionary, so you can use a TStringList instead. Store your TList of PVirtualNodes in the Objects property.

Comment: @Rob - Yes I have Delphi 2010. Aaah, I think I get it! Store the User ID as a string, and with it a TList of PVirtualNodes?? :D

Comment: You have Delphi 2010? Then you have TDictionary and generic TList. You even asked [a question about generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601822/using-angle-brackets-i-have-seen-people-using-tlistpsomething) recently. Please do as I suggested two days ago and use a `TDictionary<string, TList<PVirtualNode>>`. I even wrote the lookup code for you. I've been assuming your Skype ID is a string. If it's something else, then use *that* as the dictionary's key type instead.

Comment: @Rob Yes, but the thing was that I did not really understand how you wanted me to use the TDictionary, as I had no clue how it worked. :) I will try this later, since theres a bunch of stuff that has to be recoded in order for this to work properly, but you indeed provided the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume for simplicity sake that "Todd" is contained in a class used by the TreeView to create the entries.
As long as your TreeView is requesting it's information from that class, you could get away by adding the boolean check in the class itself and invalidate the treeview.
When the tree repaints itself, it will use your class to set the checkboxes accordingly.

I know VirtualTreeView is fast enough to perform this on several thousands of entries in a split second.

Comment: The thing is, my data is tied to the Treeview, I store it in PVirtualNode. I know thats bad, but thats how I started out, and I dont want to rewrite 5000 lines of code for this project - atleast not now :P

Comment: @David - Of course I want to solve it, but rewriting the whole project just for this would take too much time, mainly because I'm aiming for a release on Monday.

Comment: @Jeff Use a virtual control is the way to solve performance problems when there is a lot of data. You've elected not to use a virtual control and are paying the penalty.

Comment: @David - I believe you saw my other question asking how to make one, right? Well, still didn't figure it out..

Comment: @Jeff I was reading all your questions and I think your real problem is your design, maybe my advice will not help in this project but in the future will help you develop more clear and easy to maintain software. do not tide your domain object with there presentation . use more OOD is the bottom-line

Comment: @Najem - Yes, and that is what I will be working on once I am finished with this project. :)

Answer (score 0):

For traverse over all nodes may be usefull function GetNext(PVirtualNode, bool childs)
like (excuse for C++ code)

```
TVirtualNode* parent=NULL;
TVirtualNode* node=VST->GetFirst();
 while (node)
    {
    data=static_cast<TreeItemData*>(VST->GetNodeData(node));
    //doo something with node, data
    node=VST->GetNext(node, true);
    }
```