# Using Angle Brackets (I have seen people using TList<PSomething>)

Tags: delphi, generics, casting, tlist

I see people declaring their TLists like

```
MyList : TList<PSomeType>;
```

Whereafter when they create it, they do

```
MyList := TList<PSomeType>.Create;
```

So I asume that by doing that, they **won't** have to typecast the MyList.Items[I] whenever they are using it, like:

```
ShowMessage( PSomeType(MyList.Items[I]).SomeTextProperty );
```

So instead they would just do

```
ShowMessage( MyList.Items[I].SomeTextProperty );
```

Is that correct?

If so, then why can't I get it to work in Delphi 2010? I am trying exactly that - Declaring my list as

`MyList : TList<PSomeType>;`

But the compiler says:

> Undeclared Identifier: TList<>

What am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These people are using a generic list.  `TList<T>` is a generic version of TList, and it's declared in the unit `Generics.Collections`, not in `Classes`, where `TList` is.  Add `Generics.Collections` to your **uses** list and you should be fine.

Comment: 20 seconds faster. :) +1, and deleting my answer.

Comment: +1 - will mark as Answer once S.O allows me. Thank you! :) Also, seen your RPG Maker, very nice man!

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks. It's been a really rewarding project to work on.